# Automatically execute mssql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file

I'm trying to make a way to do automatic backups.
Since I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express I (apparently) can't use the agent. So I've found a sql script to do the backup. I'm using a bat file linked with windows task scheduler to launch the script every day. Here's the bat:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S 
>   (local)\SQLExpress -i C:\DBbackups\SQLExpressBackups.sql

sql:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MuOnline TO  DISK = N'C:\DBbackups\Online' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Online Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE Ranking TO  DISK = N'C:\DBbackups\Ranking.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Ranking Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE MU2003_EVENT_DATA TO  DISK = N'C:\DBbackups\2003_EVENT_DATA.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'2003_EVENT_DATA', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

BACKUP DATABASE SCFMuTeam TO  DISK = N'C:\DBbackups\SCF.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'SCF Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10

GO
```

The sql works fine and creates the backups but I have to execute it manually - so when the task scheduler runs the bat file it doesn't execute the sql - is this an error with the bat file or do i need to add to the sql?

Comment: Are there any errors or informational messages in the eventlog?

Comment: I recently did this myself. Make sure the account you're using for task scheduler has database backup rights on the sql server.

Comment: Edit - i think I'm not using the task scheduler correctly.. the batch wasn't working so i tried adding it like this http://i.imgur.com/cU5FTrb.png is this incorrect?

Comment: Use .cmd file instead of .bat (if you're not doing so already :)). In task scheduler, always specify startup working folder (same as cmd file location). In task scheduler, set credentials (your user account and password) and check "allow run with highest privileges" (or how exactly that checkbox is named). Should work.

Comment: the cmd prompt just opens and closes instantly :/ @Arvo

Comment: What result does task scheduler show? Must be 0x0 if succeeded. Does running your cmd file itself create backups? In task scheduler, you have to run x:\wherever\backup.cmd, without arguments, starting in x:\wherever, under your credentials, possibly with highest privileges. (We have set such backups up in countless times - there must be very simple mistake somewhere.)

Comment: inside the .cmd : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S (local)\SQLExpress -i C:\DBackups\SQLExpressBackups.sql      in task scheduler: Program: C:\Users\user\Desktop\sqlbak\runsqlbak.cmd  Arguments: none Start in:C:\Users\User\Desktop\sqlbak\    not sure if the start-in is correct?

Comment: and running the .cmd doesn't create the backups or launch the .sql script  hm..  @Arvo

Comment: Hmm... Put two more commands into cmd file - on first and last rows write "pause" (without quotes of course) - this way you should see, what happens inside cmd file, what error you get and similar.

Comment: here's what i got:  http://i.imgur.com/icvfxUz.png not sure if i entered the pause command correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen is not correct. Put `SQLCMD.EXE` into program to run and 
     `-S (local)\SQLExpress -i C:\DBbackups\SQLExpressBackups.sql`
 as argument

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Ok, it loads the bat now and i get the dos prompt - it flashes for a few seconds and then shows some text for a split second and closes. The sql doesn't seem to execute as the backups arn't there.